# error in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am getting an error as below:

> For dependency Dependency
>   {groupId=weblogic,
>   artifactId=webservices, version=9.2,
>   type=jar}: system- scoped dependency
>   must specify an absolute path system
>   Path

Not sure what is wrong. I have the environment variable configured which I am using in pom.xml

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using `system` scope you have to provide an absolute path to the dependency (as opposed to any other dependencies, which are searched in Maven repositories). See [System Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) in *Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism*.

Example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Why don't you just install your third-party artifact in your local/company repository?

**EDIT**: If you have `systemPath` defined but suspect that environment variable is not resolved, you will get the following error (note the presence of variable in the path):

```
The project ... has 1 error
'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for weblogic:webservices:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${env.BEA_HOME}/lib/xyz.jar @ line ...
```

But if Maven discovers the variable and resolves it properly, the error message quoted above will contain already resolved directory (not a placeholder). Tested on Ubuntu/Maven 3.

Comment: Thank for the quick reply, I have a system path configured similar to the one above. But the problem I think now is that somehow the environment varable is not resolved. I have it like this: ${env.BEA_HOME}/lib/xyz.jar and I have BEA_HOME configured as an environment variable. But still getting error. I am working on a windows 7 box if that helps.

Comment: This is all very well, except when you want to use something like tools.jar, which is under the JDK/lib directory, and not JDK/jre/lib.  So on the one hand, the Maven documentation says "${java.home} specifies the path to the current JRE_HOME environment use with relative paths to get for example:
<jvm>${java.home}../bin/java.exe</jvm>" and on the other, it complains when you do that for system path.  Surely it would be better for the java.home property to be equivalent to the environment variable and then call the path to the JRE subdirectory something like ${jre.home}?

Comment: Try with ${project.basedir} if other maven environment variables such as ${session.executionRootDirectory} did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your 'Dependency' element from the pom?

Guessing that it's of scope 'system' and that there's a path in there, and that path is a *relative* path (eg '../../someJar.jar') instead of an absolute path (eg /opt/someDir/someJar.jar).

Maven needs an absolute path.

As a side note, you might want to look in to creating a local shared repository for non-public shared jars and steer away from the 'system' scope.  System scope can bite you on the rear when the build is done in other environments.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to build the arquillian-was-embedded-8 artifact.  I'm using Win 7 64-bit as well.  Using Git, I cloned the Arquillian Embedded WAS project within NetBeans and was faced with the same error.  I changed my OS Environment variable while I had NetBeans open.  Typically, you have to close all Windows Explorer windows and Command Prompt windows for the Environment variable to take effect.  I took a chance and closed NetBeans as well.  Upon opening NetBeans again, the project resolved the ${env.WAS8_HOME} variable.  Strange...but whatever.